# Grid-like, Multiple Responsive Images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently putting together a showcase website, where in the main content area there needs to be a number of images/items, layed out in a box-like-sequence next to and on top of each other...

http://jsfiddle.net/bdv3t/

How would I go about making it so that when the browser window is brought in and made smaller, that each of these images/items gradually scales down and fits proportionality to the container that it is in (so on a large screen there are roughly 8 images/items left to right, which would be the same as on a smaller screen, only the dimensions of each of the images are smaller)?

I've had a look into using responsive images such as [this](http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/) and [this](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/responsive-images/) but with no luck, as it makes only the one image full-width.  If I can, I'd like to avoid using tables and prefer a CSS-HTML method over a JS, but if all else fails, a JS method should suffice.

Comment: This could be done without using jquery either. Check my answer in which I have updated your fiddle using `@media` css . Do the required image size adjustment in the @media query so that when the window gets resized then the images should have the specified width and height.

Comment: This is not what I am after, but thank you anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously this can be reworked, but something along the lines of...

http://jsfiddle.net/LAWNQ/

Answer (score 1):

Include jQuery in your page, e.g.:

```
<script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Add a class to all of your puzzle pieces, e.g.:

```
<li><img class="pieces" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="1" width="200" height="200"/></li>
<li><img class="pieces" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="1" width="200" height="200"/></li>
// etc.
```

Include something like this JavaScript (this one will make your puzzle pieces 1/5 of the window size):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        $(".pieces").width($(window).width() / 5).height($(window).height() / 5);
    });
});
```

I tested this with your Fiddle and it worked fine.  To include jQuery in your Fiddle, select it on the left as the framework (e.g., jQuery 1.7.2).  Then add the class name to the pieces and the script in the JavaScript box.  Test until you get the exact behavior you want.

**Edit**: If you want to minimize pixel distortion, have a number of different image sizes and reset the image source just before resizing, to the closest size available.  For example, let's say you have 400x400, 300x300, 200x200, 100x100, and 50x50 image sizes for your tiles.  The JavaScript would change to something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    updatePieceSize = function() {
        var side, imgSize, src;

        side = Math.min($(window).width(), $(window).height()) / 5;

        if (side >= 350) {
            imgSize = "400x400";
        } else if (side >= 250) {
            imgSize = "300x300";
        } else if (side >= 150) {
            imgSize = "200x200";
        } else if (side >= 75) {
            imgSize = "100x100";
        } else {
            imgSize = "50x50";
        }
        src = "http://dummyimage.com/" + imgSize + "/000/fff";

        $(".pieces").attr("src", src).width(side).height(side);        
    };

    $(window).on("resize", updatePieceSize);
    updatePieceSize();
});
```

Comment: Hopefully I've understood you correctly and applied the changes as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/a9U32/.

However, it seems to distort the images when resizing.

Comment: Yes you applied it correctly.  The images are resized by the browser so there will be some pixel distortion.  If you want to minimize this distortion, just before resizing, change the image URL to an image closest to the size you are going to set.  Then you get almost no distortion, and the fluid resizing you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited fiddle just check and if you want something else then reply.](http://jsfiddle.net/bdv3t/3/)

> @media queries solution.

Comment: I've had a look into using @media queries as well, but I am after a more fluid/liquid style for this layout.

Comment: have you checked the fiddle or not?

Comment: Of course.  It jumps from 1 size to a smaller version, but as I mentioned...I'm after a fluid, gradual reduction in image sizes and a constant number on all screens.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in having multiple sources for the images, so they can scale up more pleasantly, you might want to try one of these:

- Scott Jehl's popular [picturefill polyfill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill), which does the image swapping 'automagically'
- My [Jquery.Pikshur plugin](https://github.com/geekytime/jquery.pikshur), which gives you a bit more fine-grained control, if you're into that sort of thing