# How to make a grid of responsive images that will not stack on top of each other with small screen resolution

Tags: android, html, css, image

I have seen this posted as a similar question here on SO, so please forgive me if my problem sounds a bit redundant. I believe it is not.

I have a grid of images that ARE NOT UNIFORM in size. I am trying to responsively scale down the grid of images using CSS so when viewing on different screen sizes (mainly for Android tablets) the images all shrink down uniformly and do not stack on top of each other. I attempted applying the max-width:100% on a class applied to the  tags but it only works with the real big images but the smaller ones it does not, it just stacks them. Here is the URL: http://www.thebeachschool.eq.edu.au/freshwater-app/ (go to the contributors tab). Below is my CSS:

```
div#contributor-row-1, div#contributor-row-2, div#contributor-row-3 {max-width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: center; }
div#contributor-row-4 {max-width: 100%; text-align: center;}
div#contributor-row-1 img {padding-right:20px; max-width: 100%; }
div#contributor-row-2 img {padding-right:25px; max-width: 100%;}
div#contributor-row-3 img {padding-right:17px; max-width: 100%;}
div#contributor-row-4 img {padding-right:8px; max-width: 100%;}
```

The full HTML is a bit messy but simply put it looks like this:

```
<div id="contributor-row-1">
<img><img><img><img>
</div>
<div id="contributor-row-2">
<img><img><img><img>
</div>
<div id="contributor-row-3">
<img><img><img><img>
</div>
<div id="contributor-row-4">
<img><img><img><img>
</div>
```

As the images are not uniform in size, its making life hard for me and I don't think I will be able to achieve what I want. I tried using the solution here at [Grid-like, Multiple Responsive Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822978/grid-like-multiple-responsive-images) but it deals with a uniform grid of images that are all the same size.

My question is, can there be a CSS solution without using media queries for all the possible breakpoints of pixel resolutions? I'd love if all the images I was working with were the same size, but they are logos of organisations and they are all different dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `max-width: 100%` to images and `width: 100%` to the parent anchors:

```
div#contributor-row-1 a { width: 100%; }
div#contributor-row-1 img { padding-right: 20px; max-width: 100%; }
```

**Edit:** Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/S36RV/), hope helps

Comment: Thanks heaps for your quick reply but it did not work for me unfortunately. I have updated the css and html at the URL I provided in the question.

Comment: I am testing in chrome (pc) and it works... Let me test in my android :) Well I can't because I need those rules on your web. Anyway, I will make a jsfiddle for you

Comment: Sweet, I am testing on Google Chrome on Mac. I have source files if you wanna go there but I don't want to make too much trouble for you, JSFiddle or PasteBin sounds good.

Comment: I edited my post already with a jsfiddle.. I will check it on mac

Comment: Thanks for the JSFiddle. I just put together my own jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Khg8z/ and it still stacks and then shrinks down the image when the browser window becomes smaller than the standard image. I am looking for a way to shrink all images uniformly in the row when the browser window gets smaller. Do I have to give each image a max-width of 20% or something?? Like the JSFiddle here @ http://jsfiddle.net/LAWNQ/. My problem is that all images will not be the same dimension.

Comment: I can't find the problem. The images should have `max-width: 100%` in css. Then, each image should have its width. The images will adjust to their parent element (the container element). I updated your fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/LAWNQ/31/**

Comment: Hey @kmsdev, I have accepted your solution. I did need to do some extra tinkering on my end. I can see now that I had to give the tag containing each element a max-width (distributed from 100%). I was hoping to avoid this but it makes sense. Would work superb if all images were the same size.